# SQL - Select the longest substrings

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data like that.

```
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
EF
EFG    
IJ
IJK
IJKL
```

and I just want to get ABCDE,EFG,IJKL. how can i do that oracle sql?

the size of the char are min 2 but doesn't have a fixed length, can be from 2 to 100.

Comment: If you had "IJKLM", would you choose all three values or just "IJKLM"?

Comment: Although it is logical, please explain - at least the next time - the **rule** clearly. For instance "*the strings of the maximum length*" or "*strings of length 4*".

Comment: @GordonLinoff - just IJKLM

Comment: And if you had ABCDEFG on the list would you still include EFG? Are we matching any substring or only prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event that you mean "longest string for each sequence of strings", the answer is a little different -- you are not guaranteed that all have a length of 4.  Instead, you want to find the strings where adding a letter isn't another string.

```
select t.str
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where substr(t2.str, 1, length(t.str)) = t.str and
                        length(t2.str) = length(t.str) + 1
                 );
```

Do note that performance of this query will not be great if you have even a moderate number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Select all rows where the string is not a substring of any other row. It's not clear if this is what you want though.

```
select t.str
from table t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table t2
    where instr(t1.str, t2.str) > 0
);
```